# What is it here in this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjects

> The virus is mutations constantly, and each time, there's a new lottery ticket. And once in a while, it really, whatever number appears they get the winning ticket placed randomly found the right set of mutations that allows them to invade the human body.

I think there has to be comma between randomly and found. That makes subject *They* take two verbs, get and found. But I am not sure with my thoughts.

Plus, what is the usage of "it" in this sentence? I think this it refers to lottery ticket at front but I can't find any verbs in here so I just get confused.

Comment: It seems muddled, although I think I know what’s trying to be said. Nothing here will be fixed by commas.

Comment: It's gibberish.